# Top toolbar is not showing in wordpress admin panel

Tags: admin, dashboard

Today I came over a very interesting and confusing problem. I developed a wordpress website in my localhost and it run perfectly. But when I moved that site in my server I saw a strange thing. When I logged in my admin panel (..wp-admin/index.php) my toolbar isn't showing up and any widgets that were showing fine in the dashboard in my localhost are gone! And also the screen option and help buttons aren't working. And when I hover over my menu items in the admin menu section sub menus were shown in my localhost, but here nothing. but everything works fine when i'm not in the index.php page. any idea from the experts?

Comment: Mods, please migrate this to the WordPress site so we can merge things appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've a solution of my problem. I used chrome developer tool to find out the differences between the sites in my server and in my localhost. While inspecting the source I found following error-

```
<div class="inside">
<br>
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Out of memory (allocated 43778048) (tried to allocate 132605 bytes) in <b>/home/easyitca/public_html/samples/movierez/wp-includes/wp-db.php</b> on line <b>787</b><br>
</div>
```

and then i googled for the memory allocation problem. Then I added following in my wp-config.php file as suggested-

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');
```

but still it was saying same problem. And then I increased the memory limit from 64M to 128M and it worked!

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M');
```